# Reference request: Allard's regularity Theorem for smooth submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, submanifold

Allard's regularity Theorem (Theorem 5.2, https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf) asserts that a varifold can be locally written as a graph. Moreover, it gives a lower bound on the size of the domain in which this is possible. The size depends on the size of subsets of varifolds where balls approximate the size of Euclidean balls of the same dimension.

I am not well versed in geometric measure theory and would like this Theorem for submanifolds of Euclidean space but I can't find it formulated anywhere. The abstract in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3963.pdf) says the following:

"In the special case when V is a smooth manifold translates to the
following: If $\omega^{-1} \rho^{-n}Area(V \cap B_{\rho}(x))$ is sufficiently close to 1 and the unit
normal of V satisfies a $C^{0,\alpha}$ estimate, then $ V \cap B_{\rho}(x)$ is the graph of a
$C^{1,\alpha}$ function with estimates."

I would like a theorem of the following form.

Suppose $V$ is a closed smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the second fundamental form of $V$ is bounded by $C$ and its derivatives by $C^2$ with positive injectivity radius  $r_V$. Then there is a radius $R(C,r_V)>0$ such that for any $p \in V$ there is a function $u_p$
$$
B_R(p) \cap V = graph(u_p)
$$
where $B_R(p)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$

**Edit:** For anyone interested, I found the answer to my question in Theorem 3.8 of
https://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/schur.pdf

Comment: I'm confused. It follows from the implicit/inverse function theorem that every $C^k$ manifold ($1\le k\le\infty$) is locally a graph of a $C^k$ function.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but not in a quantitative way. I would like to find something like a lower bound for when it is possible to do so. I'm looking for a lower bound on the radius $\rho(V)$ such that it is possible to represent the submanifold as a graph

Comment: Unit normal suggests a hypersurface. Certainly if we have bounds on the derivative of the Gauss (normal) map, we can tell when the normal stays within a certain hemisphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think so, too. But I am unable to prove it. The radius should depend on the injectivity radius of the hypersurface and the derivatives of the Gauss map as you said.

Comment: Think about maximal principal curvatures. Offhand, I don’t yet see the relevance of the injectivity radius.

Comment: @TedShifrin I thought it might be a problem if the surface almost touches itself. Like a torus where you could of a small segment.

Comment: The difficulty in Allard's theorem lies elsewhere (it's in greater generality, after all). Of course, you need some assumptions to get a lower bound. What assumptions do you propose? (please include it in the question)

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I edited the kind of theorem I'm looking for with assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. If you like, you can post the reference you found as an answer. That could help other people that come here with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the a source that asserts that a domain, wherein a submanifold $V$ of Euclidean space can be written as a graph, contains a ball whose radius only depends: Proposition 3.8 in

https://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/schur.pdf

The Theorem is formulated for submanifolds whose second fundamental form is bounded by $1$ but after a rescaling argument it follows that the radius depends only linearly on the norm of the second fundamental form.